# Issue Submitting Reactjs Form to Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, forms

I have been able to submit a reactjs form to a rails mode, where the field existed in the same table, where the `name="coffee_bean[country_id]"` inserts the id of `country` into the `coffee_beans` table. This is in the form for coffee_bean.

As an example, the code below works:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';
import makeAnimated from 'react-select/lib/animated';

class Country extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      countries: []
    }
  }

  getCountries() {
    axios.get(`/countries.json`).then(res => {
      const countries = res.data;
      this.setState({countries});
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCountries()
  }

  render() {
    let countryItems = this.state.countries.map(country => ({value: country.id, label: country.country_name}));
    return (<div className="">
      <label htmlFor="coffee_beans_country_id">Country</label>
      <Select isClearable="isClearable" components={makeAnimated()} id="country" name="coffee_bean[country_id]" options={countryItems}/>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default Country
```

However, I'm now trying to replicate this, but for a joins table, and here I'm getting stuck.  I currently have the code below, but this isn't updating anything.

(just showing the different render section for brevity)

```
render() {
  let flavourItems = this.state.flavours.map(flavour => ({value: flavour.id, label: flavour.name}));
  return (
    <div className="">
      <label htmlFor="flavours">Flavours
        <small>(You can select more than one)</small>
      </label>
      <Select isMulti="isMulti" isClearable="isClearable" components={makeAnimated()} id="flavour" name="coffee_roast[flavour_id]" options={flavourItems}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**My Rails Models**

```
class CoffeeRoast < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :coffee_flavours
    has_many :flavour, through: :coffee_flavours

class Flavour < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :coffee_flavours
  has_many :coffee_roasts, through: :coffee_flavours

class CoffeeFlavour < ApplicationRecord #joins table
    belongs_to :flavour
    belongs_to :coffee_roast
```

**working rails form**
This would be the equivalent in rails.

```
<%= collection_check_boxes :coffee_roast, :flavour_ids, Flavour.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name do |cb| %>
<% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text } %>
```

**Rails Console**

```
Processing by CoffeeRoastsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jqLxq5Zw3/QIj169H5oAhQ3g69397xcTFEqpRr7x6q/Apfy8x9bcFhwv0NX41eWgYfNILA3OFnTadRqcpDDXrA==", "coffee_roast"=>{"roaster_id"=>"6", "name"=>"Los Rosales", "coffee_bean_ids"=>["", "5"], "flavour_ids"=>"3", "style"=>"Espresso", "strength"=>"Medium"}, "commit"=>"Update Coffee roast", "id"=>"los-rosales"}
```

`flavour_id` does not look like an array and I'd expect it to be like `coffee_bean_ids.  This then tells me`flavour_ids is not permitted, yet I do have this as a param in the controller.

**coffee_roasts_controller**

```
class CoffeeRoastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_coffee_roast, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /coffee_roasts
  # GET /coffee_roasts.json
  def index
    @coffee_roasts = CoffeeRoast.all
    @flavours = Flavour.all
    @meta_title = meta_title 'Coffee Roasts'
    @meta_description = 'A huge selection of coffee'

  end

  # GET /coffee_roasts/1
  # GET /coffee_roasts/1.json
  def show
    @coffee_roast = CoffeeRoast.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @flavour = Flavour.all
    @meta_title = meta_title @coffee_roast.name
    @coffeeroastcount = CoffeeRoast.where(roaster: @coffee_roast.roaster)
    @commentable = @coffee_roast
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @sameroaster = CoffeeRoast.where(roaster: @coffee_roast.roaster).where.not(name: @coffee_roast.name)

  end

  # GET /coffee_roasts/new
  def new
    @coffee_roast = CoffeeRoast.new
  end

  # GET /coffee_roasts/1/edit
  def edit
    @coffee_roast = CoffeeRoast.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /coffee_roasts
  # POST /coffee_roasts.json
  def create
    @coffee_roast = CoffeeRoast.new(coffee_roast_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @coffee_roast.save
        format.html { redirect_to @coffee_roast, notice: 'Coffee roast was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @coffee_roast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @coffee_roast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /coffee_roasts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /coffee_roasts/1.json
  def update
    @coffee_roasts = CoffeeRoast.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @coffee_roast.update(coffee_roast_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @coffee_roast, notice: 'Coffee roast was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @coffee_roast }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @coffee_roast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /coffee_roasts/1
  # DELETE /coffee_roasts/1.json
  def destroy
    @coffee_roast.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to coffee_roasts_url, notice: 'Coffee roast was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_coffee_roast
      @coffee_roast = CoffeeRoast.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def coffee_roast_params
      params.require(:coffee_roast).permit(:name, :slug, :image, :flavours, :style, :strength, :roaster, :roaster_id, coffee_bean_ids:[], flavour_ids:[])
    end
end
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: No errors.  The only thing that doesn't look correct is the value submission in rails.  I'll add the log to the OP.

Comment: You don't submit a form to a model in MVC. You submit it to a controller which updates/creates/destroys the model. You should add the relevant controller to the question

Comment: Thanks @max. coffee_roasts_controller, added.

Comment: Have you checked that the select element has the [`multiple` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Attributes)? I'm not really that familiar with react but you should be able to swap `isMulti` with just `multiple`. You should also use `name="coffee_roast[flavour_ids]"` not `coffee_roast[flavour_id]`.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but can you try `name="coffee_roast[flavour_id][]"` instead of `name="coffee_roast[flavour_id]"` ?

Comment: That was it @RocKhalil !  Thanks, now works a charm.

Comment: @SimonCooper glad it helped :-) basically, when submitting an array, this is the best way to do it in terms of params (from a form) unless you're willing to submit it from an ajax call